# Get Ancestor featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I've been trying to get the ancestors post ID to show its featured image on all sub pages, but I can only ever get combinations that work as top level and sub page, never a third page down.

The setup is currently:

Page 1

- Sub Page 1
- Sub Page 2

  - Sub Sub Page 1

I want the featured image on Page 1 to display on page 1, sub pages and sub sub pages.

This one is straight out of the codex which says:

```
global $post;
$parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
/* Get the ID of the 'top most' Page if not return current page ID */
$id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;
if(has_post_thumbnail( $id )) {
    get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'thumbnail');
}
```

But like all my other attempts it's only working with a direct parent (e.g Page 1 and Sub Pages, never Sub Sub Pages).

How can I get a third level page pick up the ancestors featured image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this hierarchy:

- Page 1

  - Page 2

    - Page 3

      - Page 4

This line, where `$post` represents Page 4:

```
$parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
```

Will return 3 IDs, for these pages, in this order:

0. Page 3

   Page 2

   Page 1

So this line:

```
$id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
$id = ($parents) ? $parents[2]: $post->ID;
```

Which means that it will only check whether page 1 has a post thumbnail. It will ignore pages 2 & 3. Because array indexes start at `0`, `count($parents)-1` means that `$id` will always be the last item in the list, which will be the top-level page.

What you want to do is loop through `$parents`, from immediate parent, to grandparent, to great grandparent, until a thumbnail is found. Then break the loop and return the thumbnail:

```
$thumbnail = ''; // We will replace this if/when we find a thumbnail.
$parents   = get_post_ancestors( null ); // null will get the current post.

foreach ( $parents as $post_id ) { // Loop through parent pages.
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) { // Check if this ancestor has a thumbnail.
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'thumbnail' ); // If it does, get it...
        break; // ...then stop looping.
    }
}

echo $thumbnail;
```

The problem with this code is that if the current page has a thumbnail, it won't get displayed, because we're only looping through parents. The simplest way to get around this is to add the current page ID to the list of IDs we're looping through:

```
$thumbnail = ''; // We will replace this if/when we find a thumbnail.
$parents   = get_post_ancestors( null ); // null will get the current post.

array_unshift( $parents, get_the_ID() ); // Add the current page to the list of pages we're checking.

foreach ( $parents as $post_id ) { // Loop through parent pages.
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) { // Check if this ancestor has a thumbnail.
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'thumbnail' ); // If it does, get it...
        break; // ...then stop looping.
    }
}

echo $thumbnail;
```

Comment: That's a great answer Jacob, I appreciate the explanation, I understand it much better now.